# Restore deleted merged branch

Tags: git, branch

I created a PR from develop to master and accidentaly toggled delete develop upon merge.
How can I restore the branch with full commit history?

edit - I have a copy of that branch locally

thanks!

Comment: `git checkout -b develop HEAD^2` from the new `master`  should be enough. With this command you are creating a new branch (`develop`) from the second parent of `master` (if `HEAD` is currently pointing to it), which is supposed to be the old `HEAD` of `develop`. If it does not work it probably means that `develop` exists locally, so you just need to push it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you need to understand is that a branch is just like a pointer to a particular commit. So if you have merged the branch to master then you have all the commits. Now how can you restore it:

1. If you have it locally then just do a `git push origin/upstream develop`. This will just push your branch on the remote. What you need to make sure is that your develop is pointing to the latest commit.
2. From the latest master commit you can check the parent commits by `git log -1 OR git log <hash>`. Your develop branch commit will be most probably your parent 2, note the hash. Just use the following commands on your local `git checkout develop && git checkout -f <hash> && git push origin/upstream develop`

My suggestion: Since you merged develop to master typically your develop and master are the same. Just recreate develop where the master branch is as it already has all your history.

Comment: Accept the answer if you think this solves your problem.